# In Backbone Collection, delete a model by link on itself

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, javascript-framework

Im just trying to delete a model from a collection, with a link on itself. 
I've attach the event to the "Eliminar button" but it seems Im losing the reference to the model element that contains it... and can't find it.. can you?:

```
(function ($) {

    //Model 
    Pelicula = Backbone.Model.extend({
            name: "nulo",
            link: "#",
            description:"nulo"
    });

    //Colection
    Peliculas = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function (models, options) {
            this.bind("add", options.view.addPeliculaLi); 
            this.bind("remove", options.view.delPeliculaLi); 
        }
    });

    //View
    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("body"),
            initialize: function () {   

            this.peliculas = new Peliculas( null, { view: this });  
            //here I add a couple of models
            this.peliculas.add([
                {name: "Flying Dutchman", link:"#", description:"xxxxxxxxxxxx"},
                {name: "Black Pearl", link: "#", description:"yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"}
            ])
        },

        events: {"click #add-movie":"addPelicula", "click .eliminar":"delPelicula"},

        addPelicula: function () {
            var pelicula_name = $("#movieName").val();
            var pelicula_desc = $("#movieDesc").val();
            var pelicula_model = new Pelicula({ name: pelicula_name },{ description: pelicula_desc });
            this.peliculas.add( pelicula_model );
        },

        addPeliculaLi: function (model) {
            var str= model.get('name').replace(/\s+/g, '');
            elId = str.toLowerCase();
            $("#movies-list").append("<li id="+ elId +"> <a href="+ model.get('link')+">" + model.get('name') + "</a> <a class='eliminar' href='#'>Eliminar</a> </li>");
        },

        delPelicula: function (model) { 
            this.peliculas.remove();
            console.log("now should be triggered the -delPeliculaLi- event bind in the collection") 
        },  

        delPeliculaLi: function (model) {
            console.log(model.get('name'));
            $("#movies-list").remove(elId);
        }

    });

    var appview = new AppView;

})(jQuery);
```

---

And my html is:

```
<div id="addMovie">
  <input id="movieName" type="text" value="Movie Name">
  <input id="movieDesc" type="text" value="Movie Description">
  <button id="add-movie">Add Movie</button>
</div>

<div id="lasMovies">
 <ul id="movies-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in this code that won't work. Your major problem here is that you don't tell your collection which model to remove. So in your html you have to assign so unique id that later will identify your model.

```
// set cid as el id its unique in your collection and automatically generated by collection
addPeliculaLi: function (model) {
  $("#movies-list").append("<li id="+ model.cid +"> <a href="+ model.get('link')+">" + 
    model.get('name') + "</a> <a class='eliminar' href='#'>Eliminar</a> </li>"
  );
},

// fetch and delete the model by cid, the callback contains the jQuery delete event
delPelicula: function (event) {
  var modelId = this.$(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
  var model = this.peliculas.getByCid(modelId);
  this.peliculas.remove(model);
  // now the remove event should fire
},

// remove the li el fetched by id
delPeliculaLi: function (model) {
  this.$('#' + model.cid).remove();
}
```

If there aren't other errors that I have overlooked your code should work now. This is just a quick fix. Maybe you should have a look at the todos example of Backbone to get some patterns how to structure your app.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html

Comment: Great that was the control I need. I just had to add a paretn() value to the element that propagates the event in delPelicula var modelId = this.$(event.currentTarget).parent().attr('id'); to make it delete the whole LI. Thanks